# nested ng-repeat with condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I'm trying to iterate through a collection of objects which are all bundled together with different dates and I want to sort them out by date. I know how to orderBy using the $filter thats ok! My problem is on the view I would like to create lets say different tables for each day in the Date. How can I go about doing this? 
I was trying now to create dynamically arrays for each date. But i can't seem to use push when I do it. And it seems unnecessary work...

```
 `$scope.modules['d'+currentDay+''].push(obj);`
```

With the orderBy works fine I just don't know how to check if the day has changed on the ng-repeat and close table and open another. ( In this case I was using lists )

**Controller.js:**

```
$scope.modules = orderBy( $scope.array , $scope.predicate , $scope.reverse );
```

**View:**
    `<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="module in modules">{{module.title}}</li>`
`

Is there a way to use filter conditions for this instead of all this work 
of separating the different modules in the controller into different arrays?

**EDIT**

Better way of putting the question.

If nested ng-repeat. How do I break/stop one of then? Is it possible

```
ng-repeat="day in days"

ng-repeat="module in modules"
```

lets say I want to break the second one once the module.day != day and move to next day in days. Is that possible?

Comment: I could use nested ng-repeat. first one with iterating the numbers of days 1-5 second iterating the elements and checking if days match?

Comment: would you mind providing some test data/creating a plunkr. im not sure a `break` is necessary. you could just tell it to not output anything if the conditions arent met. Sure that would continue to iterate over the items, but unless thats an extremely large data set, i wouldnt be too worried about the performance

Comment: @DiogoBarroso, are you trying to group-by date and have each group of items with a specific date be in a table?

Comment: Yes New Dev exaclty that.

Comment: But How would i go about doing that?

Comment: You'd need to create the proper data structure for this. In other words, create something like: `[{day: '12/10', modules: [..]}, {day: '12/11', modules: [..]}, ...]`

Comment: ok, and then use nested ng-repeat to go through them.?